# related_name parameter name conflict in django?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, orm, foreign-keys

i have a query regarding "related_name" parameter (used while establishing a relationship between models)

suppose i assign the value to related_name= "x"

then,

1. it sets the given value to reverse relation manager name
   ex- parent_model_object.x.all()
2. it sets given name to parent model while filtering objects.
   ex - child_model.objects.filter(x__name = "manav")

so is there any chances of name conflict ? (as same name is assigned to model_class and reverse relation manager )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> so is there any chances of name conflict?

**No**: Django checks this. It will try to add the name in reverse, and it will print an error in case there is.

The [**`.filter(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#filter) by the way does *not* work with the [**`related_name=…`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name), but with the [**`related_query_name=…`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_query_name). If no `related_query_name=…` is set, it will default to the `related_name=…`, and if that is missing too, to the model name in lowercase. This is different from `related_name=…` itself, which defaults to the `modelname_set` with *`modelname`* the name of the model in lowercase.

Comment: okay! so by default related_name = model_name_set (lowercased) and related_query_name = model_name(lowercased) . but, if i assign only "related_name" a value then both parameters will contain same value ? will they conflict ?

Comment: @harshit: the `related_name` and `related_query_name` are allowed* to conflict, since the two have different uses, what is not allowed is for example two `related_name`s to the same model, of a `ForeignKey` on model `A` with name `x`, and a `related_name` on `B` to `A` with name `x`, since that would make it ambiguous. So in short, Django checks and will prevent any ambiguity.